# Compiler warning for unused immutable sink, but using _ causes test to fail

Tags: swift, swift5, combine

I have a test which verifies that a message is being published when a new device is available:

```swift
let deviceConnectedPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .deviceAdded)
            .compactMap { $0.object as AnyObject as? ConnectableDevice }

let sink = deviceConnectedPublisher.sink { _ in
    expectation.fulfill()
}
```

this works just fine but I have a compiler warning:

> Initialization of immutable value 'sink' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it

However if I take the compiler's advice and change it to

```swift
let _ = deviceConnectedPublisher.sink { _ in
    expectation.fulfill()
}
```

then my test times out, and subsequently fails. Is there a better way to be declaring my sink? Is there some way to tell the compiler it's wrong? Should this be filed as a bug? I understand why the compiler thinks that the variable is unused, but it seems like there should be a way to disable the warning in this case --or more likely-- I'm doing something not-as-intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code where you store the `AnyCancellable` in a local property named `sink`, the compiler issues the warning that you never used the variable. This means that the compiler is allowed to optimize away the variable and destroy the `AnyCancellable` immediately.

However, you are probably running your tests in a Debug build configuration. The default settings for a Debug configuration disable optimization. So the compiler does **not** optimize away the `sink` variable and only destroys it at the end of the scope. By then, I assume, you have already posted the notification you're expecting.

In the code where you use `_`, the compiler destroys the returned `AnyCancellable` immediately. This cancels your subscription to the notification publisher, so the notification is never delivered to your `sink` closure.

You can silence the warning, and indeed guarantee that the local property's value isn't destroyed until later, using the `withExtendedLifetime` function:

```
let sink = deviceConnectedPublisher.sink { _ in
    expectation.fulfill()
}

// post notification here

withExtendedLifetime(sink) { }
// Only now can sink be destroyed.
```

Answer (score 1):

What the compiler is hinting to you is that the sink needs to be *stored*. The usual thing is to write

```
deviceConnectedPublisher.sink { _ in
    expectation.fulfill()
}.store(in: &self.storage)
```

...where `storage` is a `Set<AnyCancellable>` or `[AnyCancellable]` instance property. This keeps the pipeline alive and gives it a lifetime automatically tied to the surrounding object (e.g. the view controller).